# Does Googlebot respect the cache-control header?

Tags: seo, googlebot, web-crawlers

Does Googlebot respect the cache-control header? By setting an appropriate cache-control header, can one improve the crawl efficiency?

Comment: I don't believe they do. I often hear them say that the bot aggressively caches. Maybe cache control can push them to cache even longer.